# macOS error: The application is not open anymore

Tags: macos, applications, error

I'm attempting to launch a macOS application.

When I select the file from Applications, or double-click the app's icon, I get the alert message:

[image: The application "APP_NAME.app" is not open anymore.]

> The application "APP_NAME.app" is not open anymore.

I know it's not open... I want to launch the app!

What is the meaning of this error? How can I launch the application?

Answer (score 2):

I encounter this regularly. Usually I can track it down to the application immediately crashing - but Finder/the taskbar do not get notified and no way to remedy.

Unfortunately there is no easy fix.

What usually works is:

- In most cases I encounter it is solved by deleting/reinstalling the app.
- Quite often it helps to reboot and try again.

I know - both approaches are very disappointing for 2021.

Two rather sophisticated tips - that require some understanding and may leave you with a system that will not work without reboot(!) - and unfortunately rarely help are:

- You can try to use "Activity Monitor" to assure the app and related processes are really shut down, and try again after this.
- to launch an app from command line works  more often - but if it works it will leave you with a *second* symbol for the app in the dock - or in case of error might give a little more info what is going on.